# separater and list-group from bootstrap are flowing through divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/yyoJGR

Why is the white separater and the list-grouping flowing through the divs or the parent row?

```
<div class="container columnStyle">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-same-height">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-height">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s7.postimg.org/agarkavmj/whoiswho.png"></img>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-height" >
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Who is who
                  <p>
                    <small>Organization & Processes</small>
                  </p>
                </h1>                
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
             <ul class="list-group">
               <li class="list-group-item">Org Charts  </li>
               <li class="list-group-item">GAM / KAM Charts</li>
               <li class="list-group-item">Process flow</li>             
            </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>       
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.columnStyle{
  background: #006AB3;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use the class `.container`multiple times. 
This class has a fixed `width` of `1170px`;

```
.container {
width: 1170px;
}
```

you should have only 1 `.container`for the wrapper and then, inside of it, remove the other `.container` and just use `.row`

See it in action : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogeLRb

Comment: Could I use multiple container when I make them container-fluid? They should stay within the columns not?

Comment: Why would you use multiple `.container` ? The use of .row is sufficient for a bootstrap column layout. `.container`is just used to wrap the content in a width of 1170px (depending the screen size).

Comment: OK I often want more gaps/padding with the columns/rows how you handle this with bootstrap without manually doing ? Are there any classes?